# Android doze mode interrupts WebRTC call

Tags: android, webrtc, sleep, doze

When de app is in the background for a while (usually about half an hour) the connection is broken. The logs do not show anything, even while I have created a partial wake lock and put the app on the Doze whitelist.

This causes the media flow to be stopped, which is not something we want to have. Since the called side then receives a hangup message, but the app does not, the media just stops flowing.

While trying to debug this, I also note that logcat is disconnected after a while (might be a android studio on mac issue. Have had more problem with this). So debugging this is very difficult.